# How to align label text with radio button

Tags: css

The label for each radio button is aligned until the label text is not displayed on a single line. I would like the alignment [to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjdif.png). However, it currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUlTy.png) when viewed on a small screen.

This outputs data from a MySQL database into radiobuttons.

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM cases ORDER BY price");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($case_id, $case_name, $case_price);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<li>
<input id="'.$case_id.'" name="config-prod" value="'.$case_id.'" type="radio">
<label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">'.$case_name.'         [£'.$case_price.']</label>
</li>';
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

.input-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
    .input-list li input {
        margin-right: 22px;
    }
        .input-list li input:checked + label {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 17px;
            transition: color 0.5s ease;
        }
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the line items `display: flex`. I just added this:

```
.input-list li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
label {
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

.input-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

.input-list li input {
  margin-right: 22px;
}

.input-list li input:checked+label {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul class="input-list">
  <li>
    <input id="1" name="config-prod" value="1" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="1">One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="2" name="config-prod" value="2" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="2">Two</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="3" name="config-prod" value="3" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="3">Three, a really long one... Really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really long...</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="4" name="config-prod" value="4" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="4">Fourth</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks better, but the button is off-center - it appears above the text.

Comment: @M.Tesrak I made 2 more edits... Remove `margin-top` from the labels. Added `align-items:center` and some padding to the `li`, centered.